# How can I extract my desired output from merge funciton in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have 2 datasets: one is with 10 columns and 400 rows (df1) and another one has 11 columns and 2500 rows. column 1 to 10 are the exactly same variables in both datasets. 11 of df2 is the new variable that I calculated. Now I want to merge these 2 dataframes and create a new dataframe (df3) which should contain 11 columns and 400 rows. I just simply merged df2 into df1, but the rows of df3 are 2500. what I want is to keep structure of df1 as it is (10 col & 400 rows) and add values of 11th column of df2 by matching observations of column 1 to 10 of both dfs. How should I do this in R?

```
 merge(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Add `all.x = TRUE` to your `merge`. You want a left join, not the default inner join.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Thank you for your responses! it seems there is something wrong with data. I tried many different way. But still get 2500 rows.